# Custom animation in {N}?

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to animate some CSS styles not supported by {N}.

For example, text-color, height of an element etc.

Any suggestions, ideas as to how this could be done.

A simple linear animation would be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Both height and color are supported CSS properties in NativeScript ...

Comment: Reading the documentation i see 
    opacity
    backgroundColor
    translateX and translateY
    scaleX and scaleY
    rotate are supported. But I will gladly test it out.

Comment: Oh, i meant they are supported s CSS... indeed they are not supported for CSS animations